# Modify the url automatically when using git clone

Tags: git, proxy, gnome, jhbuild

JHBuild uses the git protocoal instead of https for cloning the files. I am working in a proxy environment which prevents the cloning using the git protocol.

> git url of sample gnome repo : git://git.gnome.org/gnome-common
>
> http url of sample gnome repo: 
>   http://git.gnome.org/**browse**/gnome-common.

Is there any way to transform the git url to https format automatically when JHBuild executes the clone command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gnome moduleset defines git.gnome.org as using git:// but this can be changed in the jhbuildrc file.

Add the following line in jhbuildrc.

> repos['git.gnome.org'] = 'http://git.gnome.org/browse/'

The file is present usually in ~/.config. Create jhbuildrc file if not present.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't clone a repository with a `git://` url because of a proxy or firewall, here is a little git configuration that will force git to use `http://` even when you'll type `git://` URL.

```
git config --global url."http://".insteadOf git://
```

With this command, it will add the following lines in you `.gitconfig` :

```
[url "http://"]   
    insteadOf = git://
```

That way, you don't have to care about using `git://` or `http://` when you are cloning repo, both urls will work.

Maybe a well known tweak but discovered it lately...

Comment: If you notice the urls I mentioned you can see that there is an extra "browse" in the http version. Is there any way to take care of that?

Comment: You need to modify the url ad add the browse?

Comment: I dont think so, since it not related to git, its how your system works